# Is the multiple correlation coefficient $(R)$ undefined in the case of negative determination coefficients $(R^2)$ - Neural network models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, negative-r-squared

I noticed that in some low performance models of neural networks, the value of $R^2$ (coefficient of determination) can be negative. That is, the model is so bad that the mean of the data is better than the model.
The question is: in linear regression models, the multiple correlation coefficient $(R)$ can be calculated using the root of $R^2$. However, this is not possible for a model of neural networks, for example, that presents a negative $R^2$. In that case, is $R$ mathematically undefined?

Comment: The coefficient of determination I guess you're referring to is no longer the square of the correlation (between observed and fitted responses) as it has been adjusted for the number of parameters estimated. So, it had never had a direct interpretation as the square of that correlation. As you're stating the implication of a negative R-square is that the model is unacceptable, so it's just small print that the correlation isn't defined either.

Comment: *Adjusted* R2 can yield a negative value when there is no (or a sufficiently small) relationship.  For a linear model, it isn't possible to get a negative *unadjusted* R2 unless the intercept is suppressed (in a neural network no bias nodes, I suppose), but that shouldn't be done.  Taking the square root of R2 is just one way to compute the multiple correlation; you can always just correlate the predicted and observed response variables (y & y-hat) for an alternative calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting $R^2<0$, then I assume you are calculating according to:

$$
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$

This is how `sklearn.metrics.r2_score` does the calculation, for instance.

In that case, you are right that $R^2<0$ is possible, but this is because the above equation need not be related to $\left(\text{corr}\left(y, \hat y\right)\right)^2$ like it is in OLS linear regression with an intercept. Even in such a setting, the relationship breaks down if you go to out-of-sample predictions like I suspect are of interest to someone working on neural networks. Consequently, $\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)}$ does not seem like a valuable statistic to calculate, even if the value is a real number. The only value might be to know this statistic is imaginary, since that flags situations where performance is poor (worse than the baseline of predicting $\bar y$ every time), but we would already know that from getting $R^2<0$.

Since there are multiple featuress in your neural network, or at least one feature that nonlinearly predicts the outcome, there is not even a connection between $\sqrt{R^2}$ and the correlation between the feature and target like there is in simple linear regression. (I actually do not see much value in calculating $\sqrt{R^2}$ in linear regression, especially if there are multiple features.)

Thus, I would not worry about getting imaginary square roots of $R^2<0$. If someone demands to know the correlation:

1. Part of your job is to tell people when they have misconceptions. If someone is demanding to know a meaningless statistic or a statistic that does not mean what they think it means, your should be addressing the questions they should have asked. (It is easy to be a jerk about this, so don't be.)
2. It is easy to calculate $\text{corr}\left(y, \hat y\right)$ if someone insists on it. It might be that this value is high, perhaps even one, despite $y$ being quite different from $\hat y$, such as $y = (1, 2, 3)$ and $\hat y = (101, 102, 103)$ or $\hat y = (101, 201, 301)$. Again, it is on you to explain why a high correlation between predicted and actual values can hide major issues with performance and to do assessments that expose such such issues.